# Extjs dynamically switch tabs position in tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have tabpanel:

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    tabPosition: 'top', // it's default value
    items: [/*tabs*/]
}
```

And some button which changes layout:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Change layout',
    handler: function (btn) {
        var layout = App.helper.Registry.get('layout');
        if (layout === this.getCurrentLayout()) {
            return;
        }
        if (layout === 'horizontal') {
            newContainer = this.down('container[cls~=split-horizontal]');//hbox laout
            oldContainer = this.down('container[cls~=split-vertical]');//vbox layout
            tabPanel.tabPosition = 'top';
        } else {
            newContainer = this.down('container[cls~=split-vertical]');
            oldContainer = this.down('container[cls~=split-horizontal]');
            tabPanel.tabPosition = 'bottom';
        }
        oldContainer.remove(somePanel, false);
        oldContainer.remove(tabPanel, false);

        newContainer.insert(0, somePanel);
        newContainer.insert(2, tabPanel);

        newContainer.show();
        oldContainer.hide();

    }
```

When I change layout, me also need change the position of the tabs.
Of course changing config property `tabPosition` has no effect.

How i can switch tabPosition dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid in case of `tabpanel` the only way is to destroy the current panel and recreate it from config object with altered `tabPosition` setting. You can use `cloneConfig()` method to get config object from existing panel.